# How to query Visual Studio Team Services (was VSO) using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell cmdlets

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-power-tools

I am unable to run any of the PowerShell cmdlets provided with TFS 2013 Power Tools against a Team Services account. Problematic commands include `Get-TfsItemHistory` and `Get-TfsChangeset`. These work fine with non-hosted  instances of TFS but not Team Services.
I can successfully connect to Team Services using `tf.exe` and `tfpt.exe`.
My script is shown below together with the exception that is thrown.
Can these commands be used with Team Services and if so what am I doing wrong? 
Thanks.

```
#my Team Services credentials:
$Username = "myname@live.com"
$tfsPath = "https://myname.visualstudio.com/"
$passwordFile=".\ps-password.pwd"

# read passsword from file
# NOTE: password previously stored within file using command:
# read-host -prompt Password -assecurestring | 
#    convertfrom-securestring |  
#    out-file ps-password.pwd -ErrorAction Stop
if (!(test-path $passwordFile))
{
    throw [System.IO.FileNotFoundException] "$passwordFile"
}
$Password = Get-Content "$passwordFile" | ConvertTo-SecureString

$creds = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$Password

$tfsServer = New-Object System.Uri("$tfsPath")

$tfsCollection = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection($tfsServer,$creds)
$tfsCollection.Authenticate()

# $tfsCollection | show-object  # NOTE: content of collection looks good when viewed

# PROBLEM COMMANDS:
Get-TfsChangeset -latest -server $tfsCollection
Get-TfsItemHistory "$/" -Server $tfsCollection -Version "D2010-01-01~D2016-08-01" -Recurse -IncludeItem
```

Error generated:

```
Get-TfsChangeset : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
At ~\myScript.ps1:30 char:1
+ Get-TfsChangeset -latest -server $tfsCollection
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-TfsChangeset], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.GetTfsChangesetCommand
```

Comment: I just tried with you code at my side with my VSTS/VSO account, but didn't see any issue, the change-set can be got successfully. The error you provided occured when "Get-TfsChangeset", is there any error occur during $tfsCollection.Authenticate()? I also added the powershell script I used before to get the changeset for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Add my powershell script for your reference:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell

$tfsPath = "https://xxxxxx.visualstudio.com/"

[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection] $tfs = get-tfsserver $tfsPath

Get-TfsChangeset -latest -Server $tfs
Get-TfsItemHistory "$/" -Server $tfs -Version "D2016-07-27~D2016-08-01" -Recurse -IncludeItem
```

Comment: I get exactly the same behaviour.  The inclusion of the Add-PSSnapin statement does not change the result in my particular case because I load it as part of my powershell profile (not shown above).

Comment: Authentication works fine. Interestingly, I can access the required data using Powershell if I bypass `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Powershell` and use the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client` assembly instead.  This approach however is a lot involved and I would prefer to avoid.